# hide all html tag and show only my html tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide all html tag and show only my html tag inside javascript.

```
<div id="container">
<h4>This is H4</h4>
<h3>This is H3</h3>
</div>
```

I want to hide or remove all html tag and want to add
This

```
<div><strong>This is my new html</strong></div>
```

instead..
Can I????

Comment: for a fast and simple answer YES

Comment: `$("#container").html("<div><strong>This is my new html</strong></div>")` You can use it for achieving what you require.

Comment: Since the requirement is overwriting the body content. Try this `document.write("<div><strong>This is my new html</strong></div>");`

Answer (score 0):

try the following, hide the elements in the container and then use append to add the html that you desire using `append()`

```
$('body').children().hide();
$('body').append('<div><strong>This is my new html</strong></div> ');
```

Comment: I want to hide all html tag including <body> tag bro.. and want to show my html tag

Comment: if I can not hide body tag, I want to hide all div tag and want to show only my div tag. Can I :P :P

Answer (score 0):

If they are into a body tag you can try:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML ="<div><strong>This is my new html</strong></div>";
```